# Array in class.m and how to add values in it Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I want to add an array in the class and give it some values and call it in the main class. I am using

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray *subject;
```

but I could not access it from implementation class. i want to access it and add some random values in it.

Comment: Might it be helpful, to show the - in your consideration -  relevant portions of the "main" class and "implementation class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import "yourClass.h"
@implementation yourClass
@synthesize subject;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
subject=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil];

}
```

in your class.m below @implementation
synthesize your array

Comment: how to initialise values in it

Comment: subject=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil];

Comment: You don't need `@synthesize` any more (not for a long time) and the array can be set with `obj.subject = @[ @"one", @"two", @"three"];` from the user of the object; you don't have to do it in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from implementation class using `_subject`

**OR**

```
Synthesize your property in your `.m file`
```

like:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize subject;
```

Comment: how to give values to that array?

Comment: _subject=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B",......, nil];     and if you use 2nd way then....    subject=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B",......, nil];